# meaning of String* in scala

Tags: scala, user-defined-functions

I am reviewing an existing scala code which has a function defined as

```
def sm_func(inputStr: String*) : String = {
 // some logic
}
```

Just wondering what does String* signifies, does that mean its an array of string, sequence of strings or what?

Comment: It is to signal that is a **varidic** argument. For your method, it is just a `Seq[String]`. But your caller will see it differently `sm_func("a", "b")` instead of `sm_func(Seq("a", "b"))`. - PS: Do not use underscore _(`_`)_ as part of a function name, that is not idiomatic in Scala, we use camel case.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thanks for the explanation

Comment: @jwvh, thanks for pointing me to the duplicate. Unfortunately, i couldnt find that thread in my searches. This is exactly a duplicate of the thread you pointed me to.